# Save the last table filter query when user come back to the page

Tags: javascript, symfony

I'm new on Symfony. I have a table with 5 filters and I want to keep the state of them (save the last query) when the user come back again to that page where the table is because the filters are reset.

I've being reading about how to do it, because I have no idea. I read about html web storage, about session variable but I cant find any example of how to do it, could please someone explain me which is the best method to do it and how to apply.

Here is my filterAction on my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/filterFichas/", name="filterFichas")
 */
public function filterFichasAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $txtColectivo = $request->request->get('colectivo');
    $txtRol = $request->request->get('rol');
    $txtEstadosObjetivos = $request->request->get('EstadosObjetivos');
    $txtEstadosFichas = $request->request->get('EstadosFichas');
    $idPeriodo = $request->request->get('periodo');

    $periodo = $em->getRepository('GOCModelBundle:Periodo')->findOneBy(array('id' => $idPeriodo));


    $respuesta = array();
    foreach ($periodo->getFicha() as $ficha){
        $flag = true;

        if($txtColectivo != "todas"){
            $colectivo= $em->getRepository('GOCModelBundle:Colectivo')->findOneBy(array('nombre' => $txtColectivo ));
            if($ficha->getUser()->getColectivo() != $colectivo){
                $flag = false;
            }
        }

        if($txtRol != "todas"){
            $rol = $em->getRepository('GOCModelBundle:Rol')->findOneBy(array('rol' => $txtRol ));
            if($ficha->getUser()->getRol() != $rol){
                $flag = false;
            }
        }

        if($txtEstadosFichas != "todas"){
            if(count($ficha->getFichacontenidoestado()) > 0){
                $estadoContenido = $em->getRepository('GOCModelBundle:Estadocontenido')->findOneBy(array('descripcion' => $txtEstadosFichas ));
                if($ficha->getFichacontenidoestado()[count($ficha->getFichacontenidoestado()) - 1]->getEstadocontenido() != $estadoContenido){
                    $flag = false;
                }
            }else{
                $flag = false;
            }
        }

        if($txtEstadosObjetivos != "todas"){
            if(count($ficha->getFichaobjetivosestado()) > 0){
                $estadoObjetivos = $em->getRepository('GOCModelBundle:Estadobjetivo')->findOneBy(array('descripcion' => $txtEstadosObjetivos ));
                if($ficha->getFichaobjetivosestado()[count($ficha->getFichaobjetivosestado()) - 1]->getEstadobjetivo() != $estadoObjetivos){
                    $flag = false;
                }
            }else{
                $flag = false;
            }
        }

        if($flag){
            $respTemp = array(
                'user' => $ficha->getUser(),
                'ficha' => $ficha,
            );
            array_push($respuesta, $respTemp);
        }

    }

    return $this->render('GOCFichasBundle:Default:fichasFilter.html.twig', array(
        'usr' => $respuesta,
    ));

}
```

and here is my js action for the filter:

```
function filterFichas() {
         $.blockUI({ message: '<h4><img src="{{ asset('assets/global/plugins/cubeportfolio/cubeportfolio/img/cbp-loading.gif') }}" /> Cargando datos, por favor espere...</h4>' });
         var idPeriodo = $('#selectPeriodoActual').val();
         $( "#tabla" ).load( "{{ path('filterFichas')}}",
             {
                 colectivo:$( "#selectColectivo" ).val(),
                 rol: $( "#selectRol" ).val(),
                 EstadosObjetivos: $( "#selectEstadoObjetivos" ).val(),
                 EstadosFichas: $( "#selectEstadoFichas" ).val(),
                 periodo: idPeriodo
             },
             function() {
             $.unblockUI();
         });
     }
```

How can I save the last filter action the user did so when the user come back has the last filtered table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cookies to save your filter value.

```
$.cookie($( "#selectEstadoFichas" ).val(), 1, { expires : 10 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use the [session component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html) which is easily accessible inside your controller if it inherits the BaseController.

You can use `$this->get('session')` to retrieve the session service inside your controller. After that, the interface you can use to interact with it is pretty much the same as the parameter bags of the `Request` object you are already using (`get` and `set` methods have the same signature).

Thus, for handling a parameter, you would have to check first if it is already inside the `$request->query` parameter bag. If not, look inside the session for a value and if it is still not there, fallback to a default value (presumably `null` in your case).

You can take advantage of the second optional parameter of the [get method](https://api.symfony.com/4.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.html#method_get) that defines a default value in case nothing was found to do this in one line. After that, you can just save the retrieved value in the session so that it can be retrieved when the user comes back later.

```
$session = $this->get('session');
...
$myParam = $request->request->get('myParam', $session->get('myParam'));
if($myParam !== null)
{
    $session->set('myParam', $myParam);
}
```

By doing that, `$myParam` will be `null` if `myParam` is not defined both in the request and in the session. Either way, if the retrieved value is not null, it is stored into the session for further use.

Note however that, since we are talking about sessions here, those saved parameters will only last for the duration of the session of the user. If your user closes the web browser and comes back, previously saved parameters will be lost.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! but the one which works was the $.cookie($( "#selectEstadoFichas" ).val(), 1, { expires : 10 });